# How to refer to other queries through "m" formulas or power query?

Tags: excel, powerquery

The following line of code will create a variable of the type table with the content from a table in the spreadsheet.

Instead of referring to a table in excel spreadsheets, I want to refer to another query. — How do I do that?

`mytable = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="table_in_excel_spreadsheet"]}[Content]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your query name is a text variable, use `Record.Field(#shared, YourQuery)`

Answer (score 2):

If you're query is called Query1, it's:

`mytable = Query1`

For queries with more complicated names with spaces and special characters, like My Query, it's:

`mytable = #"My Query"`

Comment: what about if your query name is in a string variable: